# ystem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Tags: sql-server

When running my application I got an error. When I was logged in as admin it worked fine. After that, when trying to login as a standard user, I got the following error:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Source Error: 


Line 30:                 {
Line 31:                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Line 32:                     sda.Fill(dt);
Line 33:                     return dt;
Line 34:                 }

Source File: h:\Project Code\Tickandtie_472018\App_Code\bindingControl.cs    Line: 32
```

I have attached my web.config file and connection string.

### webconfig

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

        <customErrors mode="Off"/>      
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="login.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

### Binding controls##

```cs
public class bindingControl
{
   string constr = "Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=tick;Initial Catalog=TickandTie;Timeout=200;Data Source=184.168";
    //string constr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TickandTie;Integrated Security=True";
    public DataTable DataTableFill(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }

    public DataSet DataSetFill(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
```

*(snip) - The error occurs in the second method of the class.*

Both logins worked, but suddenly the user login no longer seems to.

Comment: Note that MySQL has nothing to do with MS SQL Server. They are differents DBMS

Comment: Sounds like you have/had some blocking going on.